# str_replace is replacing string on wrong place

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I am redesigning template mechanism of my one of the wordpress plugin. So the users can customized design as per their need. For this purpose. i am asking a template format string with some options which i can replace later.

Sample Template String :

```
$template = '<a href="%POST_URL%"  title="%POST_TITLE%"><img src="%POST_THUMB%" /></a>';
```

Code:

```
$temp .= $template;
$temp = str_replace("%POST_TITLE%", $ptitle, $temp);
$temp = str_replace("%POST_URL%", the_permalink(), $temp);
$temp = str_replace("%POST_THUMB%", lead_img_thumb_post($width ,$height ,$imagepath ,$icontype ), $temp);
```

Output:

```
%POST_URL%%POST_URL%%POST_URL%<a href=""  title="%POST_TITLE%"><img src="%POST_THUMB%" /></a><a href=""  title="%POST_TITLE%"><img src="%POST_THUMB%" /></a><a href=""  title="%POST_TITLE%"><img src="%POST_THUMB%" /></a>
```

Why %POST_URL% is moving ahead

Comment: Try changing the variable names

Comment: Is `$temp` empty when you append `$template` to it?

Comment: Tip: str_replace supports arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `get_the_permalink()` instead. `the_permalink()` outputs the link to the browser direction. Using the `get_whatever()` instead will cause WP to return the data, instead of outputting it.